# Database structure to store markdown text with embedded images?

Tags: mysql, database, markdown

Let's say I have some editor on my website (https://simplemde.com/) with markdown support and I want to store not only text but also images.

Table looks like this

```
posts
    id - primary key
    post_text - text
```

When user uploads image link to this image is embedded into editor but how do I store link from this post to the image? Post is not saved yet.

Possible solution (not best I think)

```
post_images
    id - primary key
    post_id - foreign key to posts(id)
    path - varchar (path to image)
```

Comment: I think someone/something would have to separate the embedded images from the text first.  Do you have a way of doing this?

Comment: They are uploaded to server during post editing

Comment: How about storing the post as a draft when the image is uploaded? Only to get the id of the post.